# Standalone Player Looks Different than Game View

Tags: view, unity-game-engine

Okay so I've built this little dodger game and everything is perfect except the standalone player doesn't match the game view visually. Pics for reference. Please let me know anything to stop this issue.

I want the standalone player to be the same as the game view.

Changing the resolution in the player settings doesn't work so far.

Unity GameView
[image: Unity GameView,]

Standalone Player
[image: Standalone Player]

Comment: If you have the answer to your question, it would be great for future visitors to see it. I see in the comment below you've figure out the solution. If you have time, please post it as an Answer and accept your own answer. Great job figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like its your `scale` settings in the Game window. It's set at 0.33 in the picture you've posted.

Try changing your view to `Free Aspect`, then adjust your camera GameObject to tighten in on your gameplay area. Or just refresh your layout, sometimes changing the aspect ratio while the Game view is smaller makes it difficult to restore the aspect you are looking for.

Reset your layout here:

Window\Layouts\Default (or whatever you prefer)

Comment: But I want the game to be a fixed aspect ratio regardless, not fit my screen resolution. Changing my layout is only going to change the placement of things on my editor.

Comment: Ok I hear you. Is your camera scripted to move away or refocus on your player object when the game starts? Or are you saying when you press `Play` in the editor and when you play the game via executable or otherwise, the camera is farther away, aka, not always in the same static position?

Comment: No it wasn't. I found a solution that was write a script that forces it to stay in one aspect ratio regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, with two different cameras rendering.

```
void Update ()
```

{
    float targetaspect = 4f / 3f; // set the desired aspect ratio
    float windowaspect = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;    // determine the current aspect ratio
    float scaleheight = windowaspect / targetaspect;    // current viewport height should be scaled by this amount

```
// obtain camera component so we can modify its viewport
Camera camera = GetComponent<Camera>();

// if scaled height is less than current height, add letterbox
if (scaleheight < 1.0f)
{  
    Rect rect = camera.rect;

    rect.width = 1.0f;
    rect.height = scaleheight;
    rect.x = 0;
    rect.y = (1.0f - scaleheight) / 2.0f;

    camera.rect = rect;
}
else // add pillarbox
{
    float scalewidth = 1.0f / scaleheight;

    Rect rect = camera.rect;

    rect.width = scalewidth;
    rect.height = 1.0f;
    rect.x = (1.0f - scalewidth) / 2.0f;
    rect.y = 0;

    camera.rect = rect;
}
```

}